# Reference column in WHERE EXISTS in a SQL Server CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, exists

I have a CTE in SQL Server with a WHERE EXISTS clause which I'm trying out instead of using joins.

```
WITH Work_Info AS
(
  SELECT 
      a.fName,
      a.lName, 
      a.workID,
      a.carID
  FROM tbl_info a
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.workID
                FROM tbl_work b
                WHERE a.workID = b.workID)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT c.carID, dbo.age_function(a.startDate, c.DOB) AS AGE
                FROM tbl_car c
                WHERE a.carID = c.carID
)
```

I'm trying to use/reference the column aliased as `AGE` in statements following the CTE, for example:

```
update tble_info a
SET adult =
   CASE WHEN AGE < 18 THEN 'NO'
```

Comment: Show your table schema.  It is unclear if AGE you want to use is calculated from tbl_car.DOB or if it exists in tble_info.

Comment: sorry I just saw this comment, I have a function that calculates age, the one parameter startDate is from tbl_info and the other DOB is from tbl_car. I realized that I wrote some of the names a bit confusing. anywho I tried GarethD's suggestion to use MERGE and it seems to be doing what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how [EXISTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) works. You cannot return values from the EXISTS subquery. You would need to use JOINs:

You can do your update as follows:

```
WITH Work_Info AS
(   SELECT  a.fName,
            a.lName, 
            a.workID,
            a.carID
            Age = dbo.age_function(a.startDate, c.DOB)
    FROM    tbl_info a
            INNER JOIN tbl_car c
                ON c.CarID = a.CarID
  WHERE     EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    tbl_work b
                WHERE   a.workID = b.workID
            )
)
UPDATE  Work_Info
SET     adult = CASE WHEN AGE < 18 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END;
```

However, I recommend not using this method (it may not even work as an updateable CTE, I haven't tested). I would instead use `MERGE` (I have had to assume the existance of an ID column as the PK in tbl_info):

```
WITH Work_Info AS
(   SELECT  a.ID,
            Age = dbo.age_function(a.startDate, c.DOB)
    FROM    tbl_info a
            INNER JOIN tbl_car c
                ON c.CarID = a.CarID
  WHERE     EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    tbl_work b
                WHERE   a.workID = b.workID
            )
)
MERGE tbl_Info a
USING Work_Info w
    ON a.ID = w.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET adult = CASE WHEN w,Age < 18 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END;
```

The reasons I prefer (and suggest) to use `MERGE` even though you are not really merging you are only updating are discussed on [sqlblog.com](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2008/03/lets-deprecate-update-from/)

---

**ADDENDUM**

To elaborate further on the main reason I prefer `MERGE` over just using `UPDATE` is that it safeguards against non deterministic updates. With the following sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT, Adult CHAR(3));
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INT, Age INT);

INSERT T1 (ID) VALUES (1);
INSERT T2 (ID, Age) VALUES (1, 5), (1, 20);
```

We can see that a single ID in T1 has two rows in T2, one where the age is over 18 and one where it is under, so if we run this update:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  T1.ID, T1.Adult, T2.Age
    FROM    T1
            INNER JOIN T2
                ON T1.ID = T2.ID
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     Adult = CASE WHEN Age < 18 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END;
```

There will be no error, and the T1 will be updated, but we don't know whether it would be set to `NO` or `YES`, since we don't know which reford of T2 will be the last encountered and "stick" in T1, when I ran the above Adult was set to `NO`, however when I change the insert to:

```
INSERT T2 (ID, Age) VALUES (1, 20), (1, 5); -- order changed
```

`T1.Adult` is set to `YES`. When I run using `MERGE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  T1.ID, T1.Adult, T2.Age
    FROM    T1
            INNER JOIN T2
                ON T1.ID = T2.ID
)
MERGE T1
USING CTE
    ON CTE.ID = #T1.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET Adult = CASE WHEN Age < 18 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END;
```

I get the following error:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Prompting me to review my query, and ensure that it is deterministic.

There are other reasons mentioned in the linked article, such as ANSI compliance (not a huge concern to me), and also updating a view using `UPDATE .. FROM` with an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` on the view will fail, but won't with MERGE, this is again something I have not yet lost any sleep over.

Don't get me wrong, I still use `UPDATE .. FROM` on occasion, but only really for large one off updates when I know for sure duplicates are not an issue as it does offer a better plan with lower IO.

Comment: Thanks GarethD! 
I will try using the MERGE.

Comment: +1 for the join UPDATE but I don't see why the MERGE would be preferable.

Comment: @ypercube I have added a better description of the benefits MERGE provides. I suspect it is more a matter of preference though, which is why I offered both solutions.

Comment: There are some issues with MERGE though, which have not been resolved yet. See Aaron Bertrand's article: [If you are using indexed views and MERGE, please read this!](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug) and Alex Kuznetsov's answer at [a DBA.SE question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/what-are-objective-business-reasons-to-prefer-sql-server-2012-over-2008-r2/14860#14860)

Comment: I had not heard of these problems before, although this usage does not apply to the main gripe of Aaron's article as this key point is not met: `you perform updates to the base table(s) using MERGE which includes both UPDATE and (DELETE or INSERT) actions;`. It is definitely something to consider though.

Comment: I added another exists, after ending the case statement, filtering out some other conditions for the update and I get "merge...must be terminated..(;)" and "incorrect syntax near 'where'"

Comment: actually I'm gonna try moving those conditions and adding them to the merge.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're not exposing AGE as a column in your CTE. It's only used in your WHERE clause so it's just acting as part of your larger EXISTS filter.

Basically, you're going to have to join tbl_car to tbl_info if you want to be able to run your age function and return the value. You're already doing that anyway in your inner WHERE clause in your EXISTS statement, so it won't be a performance hit to actually join on a.carID = c.carID and add the AGE column to your CTE definition.